# How do I get the correct sql quoted string for a .NET DbType

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I want to run an `ALTER TABLE` that adds a default value constraint to a column.

I generate this statement dynamically from a .NET program.

How do I best format and quote the value when building my sql - now that `ALTER TABLE` statements does not support parameters (Gives the error 'Variables are not allowed in the ALTER TABLE statement').

Is there a utility for that in .NET? Or another solution?

Comment: Why don't you use a stored procedure for this?

Comment: @Andreas: SP's have the exact same problem.  The SP has to construct a dynamic SQL statement while sanitizing the input.

Comment: @Andomar: But the parameters would then be already sanitized so that there is only the construction left. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Andreas: Say you pass `@defVal` to an SP, and it contains `blah'; drop database YourDB; --`.  Then if you construct an alter table like `set @sql = 'alter table ...' + @defVal`, you'll be open to SQL injection.  The proper way is `set @sql = 'alter table ...' + replace(@defVal, '''', '''''')`

Comment: @Andreas a stored procedure is only effective for DML; this is a DDL operation - it would need to use `sp_executesql`, at which point you might as well have just used a text command in the first place

Comment: @Andomar on replace: I beg to differ; `quotename` would be *vastly* preferable to `replace` here

Comment: @MarcGravell: quotename certainly makes for a 300% longer answer.  What are the advantages?

Comment: @Andomar `quotename` is only 2 more characters than `replace` - call it an extra 7 if you include the `,''''`. The reason my answer takes more code is that **to show the usage**, I made the table name, column name and constraint name *all* dynamic based on variables that could contain any string, and an example that is fully runnable in SSMS. As for the advantage - that is simple: correctness

Comment: @MarcGravell: Replace is exactly as correct as quotename.  Listing correctness as an advantage is disingenuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in TSQL; for example, say you parameterize the command, passing in `@DefaultValue`, a `varchar` which *may or may not* be a valid TSQL literal. Because we are writing DDL, we will need to concatenate and `exec`, however we clearly don't want to *blindly* concatenate, as the value could be illegal. Fortunately, `quotename` does everything we need. By default, `quotename` outputs `[qualified object names]`, but you can tell it to operate in literal escaping mode, for both single-quote and double-quote literals.

So our query that accepts `@DefaultValue` can build an SQL string:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'alter table ...';
-- ... blah

-- append the default value; note the result includes the outer quotes
@sql = @sql + quotename(@DefaultValue, '''');
-- ... blah

exec (@sql);
```

Full example:

```
--drop table FunkyDefaultExample
create table FunkyDefaultExample (id int not null)

declare @tableName varchar(20) = 'FunkyDefaultExample',
        @colName varchar(20) = 'col name',
        @defaultValue varchar(80) = 'test '' with quote';

-- the TSQL we want to generate to exec
/*
alter table [FunkyDefaultExample] add [col name] varchar(50) null
      constraint [col name default] default 'test '' with quote';
*/
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'alter table ' + quotename(@tablename)
    + ' add ' + quotename(@colName) + 'varchar(50) null constraint '
    + quotename(@colName + ' default') + ' default '
    + quotename(@defaultValue, '''');

exec (@sql);
-- tada!
```

Comment: `quotename()`'s outer quotes would be awkward for numeric columns

Comment: @Andomar you wouldn't *use* it if you thought you were adding a numeric column

Comment: What is the problem with using it with numeric columns? It seems to work as per what @Andomar said in the other answer.

Comment: This is really great. Didn't know about `quotename()`... solves a lot of what I've had troubles with.

Comment: @asgerhallas indeed, it is a really helpful method if you do a lot of meta-programming; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("alter table YourTable add constraint DF_YourTable_Col1 default '{0}'",
    inputValue.Replace("'", "''"));
```

Comment: Oh I did not know you could insert numbers in quotes too :) Silly me. Can you do that with all types?

Comment: @asgerhallas: You could, and SQL Server would try to convert them to the type of the column you're giving a default constraint.  If it's a numeric column, I set the default as a number and not a string, like `default {0}"`